# Table created from web2py has no trace in MySQl?

Tags: python, mysql, web2py

My custom `auth_user` table is accessible from web2py but it has no trace in MySQL? Is there any extra step for the integration?  (New to Web2py)

Comment: If web2py has indeed created the table in your MySQL database and inserted records that are accessible via web2py, then it isn't possible for there to be no trace of the table in MySQL. So, what exactly do you mean by "accessible from web2py"? Are you sure you are looking in the right MySQL database (and exactly how are you checking)? It might help to show your web2py code.

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking.Obviously data is being stored as well as retrieved so there must be a table.I have only one DB.Let me edit the question with few screenshots and some details.These is certainly something what I am not  doing correctly..

Comment: could not be hooked up properly to mysql and therefore using sqlite database instead